# reading data from file as list

Tags: python, string, amazon-s3, boto

i have file on s3 that contains

```
[{
        'address': 'Bramalea, L6T 0E2'
        'type': 'home'
      }, {
        'address': 'A, 46 Peel Drive, ASDF23'
        'type': 'office'
      }
}]
```

i just wanted to read **addresses** that has **type** **office** , can any body suggest me how i can iterate this data ? because its just a string
so far i am able to read this data

```
conn = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
for key in bucket.list(DIR_Name):
    data =  key.get_contents_as_string()
    print data
```

i also tried reading data using json module

```
data =  key.get_contents_as_string()
print json.loads(data)
```

its raising

```
    print json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 5 (char 8)
```

Comment: No need to be sorry for asking a question. However, you should really show what you've tried so far so that we know you've given your own question some thought. That being said, I would suggest reading about the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: Is this JSON data? It looks like it. You can use the `json` library to read in this file and then filter by whatever you want.

Comment: @ubomb question updated

Comment: This is an indirect approach, but you could have the script edit the file to add a ```a =``` in front of the first line.  This would make the file valid Python which you could them ```import``` into your script

Comment: you have an extra `{` at the end of the list.

Comment: @daouzli that was just a typo , file doesn't have that

Comment: Are the comma's a typo too? It looks like they should be after each address entry.

Comment: the code of the answer I provided below will provide you a list of addresses with type equal to office (even if the score is -1 :/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use an other module. As this is a list of dictionaries, it is easy to keep only elements with `'type'` that are `'office'`:

```
my_list = [{
    'address': 'aa, 46 Peel Centre Drive, A342',
    'type': 'home',
  }, {
    'address': 'a, 46 Peel Centre Drive, AS32',
    'type': 'office',
  }, {
    'address': 'b, 46 Peel Centre Drive, SD22',
    'type': 'home',
  }, {
    'address': 'c, 46 Peel Centre Drive, SD22',
    'type': 'home',
  }, {
    'address': 'd, 46 Peel Centre Drive, SSD222',
    'type': 'office',
  }]
addresses = [elem['address'] for elem in my_list if elem['type'] == 'office']
print addresses
```

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect in my comment to your post. Do not use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse this file because this is not valid json. Valid json only uses double quotes around its strings - not single quotes. Instead, this looks like basic python literal structures (read: basic python data types). There is a method to safely do this with potentially untrusted sources. [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should be able to help you here.